# Showing custom player / interactive canvas renderer in facebook and twitter feeds

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, twitter, metadata, head

I am trying to figure out if it's possible to render a custom canvas player or a custom video player in facebook and twitter feed. I am aware of different meta tags, which can be given in the head section of a server side rendered app. Given a youtube video url:

- In facebook feed it detects the meta fields from the head section and renders the video title, description and thumbnail

I would like to achieve something similar but it will be a canvas app. Is there any specification with respect to page load time and page size? Please point me to the specification for the same.

Comment: Facebook: No, I don’t think that is currently possible. The Instant Gaming platform allows for custom HTML5 content to be displayed directly in the feed - but if you want to get on that, I am pretty sure you need an actual game, I don’t think they will allow you to use that as a mere custom video player.

Comment: Thx @04FS Any idea on how youtube link gets converted to a video player?

Comment: That’s just OG meta tags, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#video (There is no guarantee any more however, that this will actually display as a playable inline video - Facebook has reduced the amount of such videos they show a while back, so it might just fall back to showing the thumbnail, and opening the external URL that was shared, when the user clicks.)